# When to put '*' before a pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers

I've been studying pointer for weeks but there is one thing that I just can't get.
When should one put '*' before a pointer?

For instance;

```
int x = 10;
int *p;
p = &x;        // Why doesn't p need '*'?

int *number = malloc(sizeof(int));
*number = 1;   // When number needs '*'.

char name[] = "Barack Obama";
char *name_ptr;
name_ptr = name;    // How come the variable "name" doesn't need '&' mark?
                    // Is it so that an array doesn't need a '&' mark 
                    // when it's pointed?

printf("name_ptr : %s\n", name_ptr);   // Doesn't need '*' here.

int num_basket[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
int *num_ptr;
num_ptr = num_basket;
printf("num_ptr : %d\n", *num_ptr);   // How come I need an '*' here???
```

Thank you very much for your help before hand! :)

Edit: I'm sorry that I didn't make it clear but I basically already know the definition of pointers. I just didn't understand this specific situation.

Comment: @C.B. You should post that as the answer.

Comment: This sounds like homework. If this is homework you should indicate it is, so people will help you to teach yourself not just give you an answer.

Comment: When you want to dereference the pointer.

Comment: @cbrulak - Actually, the "homework" tag is deprecated.

Comment: @HotLicks okay. Still putting that in the question is still better than nothing.

Comment: Don't feel too bad -- it is confusing.  Especially since people like to write the declaration as `int *pointer;` rather than `int* pointer;` so that it seems like you're doing a dereference in the declaration.  But in `int *pointer;` the `*` is simply saying "this is a pointer to `int`", even if there's an assignment in the statement such as `int *pointer = someExpression;`.  Entirely different from `*pointer = someExpression;`.  Clear as mud?

Comment: @cbrulak This issn't a homework. This is a question that rose in my head while doing several homeworks and I couldn't solve on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why doesn't p need '*'?

Because `p` is a pointer to `int` and it can hold the address of `int`.

> When number needs '*'.

Whe you want to [dereference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator) the pointer,i.e, to get the value stored at the address pointer points to.

> How come the variable "name" doesn't need '&' mark?
>                      Is it so that an array doesn't need a '&' mark 
>                        when it's pointed?

Array names decays to pointers to its first element (in most cases).

> Doesn't need '*' here.

`%s` expects an argument of type `char *`. `name_ptr` is of type `char *`and you do not need an `*` operator here (applying `*` to it will make it `char` type).

> How come I need an '*' here???

Because you want the value stored at the address pointer points to. Here `%d` in `printf` expects an argument of type `int` (unlike the `%s` specifier).

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I wanted to know :)

Comment: Could you specify "Array names decay to pointers to its first element"? When you say decay, you mean "to point"?

Comment: When I say *decay*, I mean to say *converted to*.

Answer (score 4):

`*` is the *deference* operator and is used whenever you need to get the value at the [address stored in the pointer](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/).

Answer (score 3):

When `p` is a pointer, adding an asterisk in front of it produces an expression `*p` that means "the value pointed to by `p`".

When `p` points to a value, it becomes an indirect representation of that value with the level of indirection equal to one. When `p` points to a pointer to a value, it is said to have a level of indirection of two, and so on. The value itself can be thought of as having a level of indirection equal to zero.

```
int x;         // Level of indirection = 0
int *p = &x;   // Level of indirection = 1
int **pp = &p; // Level of indirection = 2
```

Each operator `*` is said to decrease the level of indirection by one; on the other hand, operator `&` is said to increase the level of indirection by one.

```
int a = *p;   // p's level of indirection is one; a's level is zero. Need one *
int b = **pp; // pp's level of indirection is two; b's level is zero. Need two *s
```

Array names are an exception, because they can be interpreted as pointers to array elements, and therefore have a level of indirection equal to one with respect to their elements.

> Why some pointer operands of `printf` need an asterisk, while others don't?

The answer depends on the format specifier. `%s` takes a `char*`, `%p` takes a `void*`, and `%d` takes an `int`. See [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf)'s reference for details.

Comment: Can I start a style war with a pedantic `int* p` is correct as `int*` is the type of the variable `p`? :D

Comment: @PeterM - I agree.  I (almost) always write a declaration with the `*` to the left of the space, to associate it with the type.  Some people object to this since then `int* x, y;` might be improperly interpreted as creating two pointers, but my answer to that is to never put two declarations on the same line.

Comment: dasblinkenlight, you totally zoomed past a major point of confusion for newbies which is that `int *p = &x;` is entirely different from `*p = &x;`.  I suspect this confuses a lot of folks, and one needs to be clear about the (very confusing) distinction.

Answer (score 1):

putting a * means you are dereferencing the memory location pointed by the pointer or in other words you are accessing the memory location pointed by the pointer.So when you want to access the memory location pointed by the pointer we put a *  before the pointer.
To access the pointer itself no * is required
name_ptr and name both are pointers it is exactly as int a=int b .

Answer (score 0):

> p = &x;        // Why doesn't p need '*'?
>
> int *number = malloc(sizeof(int));
>
> *number = 1;   // When number needs '*'.

for first line address of x is attained to p variable. It means p points to x's value.
for third line p points to value of 1 (not address). That is why they are different.

> printf("name_ptr : %s\n", name_ptr);   // Doesn't need '*' here.
>
> printf("num_ptr : %d\n", *num_ptr);   // How come I need an '*' here???

for first line pointer keeps the string's address.
for second line pointer keeps the address of first member of the array.

If you change first line as

```
 printf("name_ptr : %s\n", *name_ptr);
```

This will write only first character of the array ('B').

Answer (score -1):

In layman's terms, you're following the pointer which gets you to the value at that address.